# Angular2 application design

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am very new to Angular2 and started writing hello world.

It has Modules and Component.

I am confused on designing Angular2 application.

Should we have only 1 Module say AppModule and many components like LoginComponent, HomeComponent, AboutComponent etc.

or we should have AppModule as starting point and LoginModule(containing LoginComponents), DashboardModule(containing DashboardComponents), AboutModule(containing AboutComponents) etc. and all called from AppModule.

I am thinking in a way that each screen like Dashboard can grow in future and also in terms of re usability.

Comment: follow the docs https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/style-guide.html

Comment: link is very useful.

Answer (score 0):

if you consider re-usability, flexible, scaling - so yes, as you said, use separate components that will make it easier to manage your app code later.